# Velocity Reports variable not resolving

Tags: java, velocity

In one of my velocity templates:

```
#set ($customer=$dao.executeQuery($queries.query1))
```

In the VelocityContext

**queries.query1** = "select NAME, DESCRIPTION from CUSTOMERS where ID = $parameters.customerId"

**parameters.customerId** = 123.

For some reason the $parameters.customerId variable in query1 is not being replaced. dao.executeQuery is returning a SQLException.

The user says this exact configuration worked in Velocity 1.4, but now that it doesn't work in Velocity 1.7. Has there been a change in how variables are handled in the Velocity Context or is my user telling fibs? It also goes without saying that I don't have too much experience with Velocity, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: What does just `$parameters` output?

Comment: If I call it from within the query, it has the same result.